# How to copy texts from multiple pages in Vi editor

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I am opening the file in `VIM` editor.I am trying to copy a text which is present in multiple pages. At a time maximum I can select the text that is visible only on the current page when I open the file in vim editor. Is there a way to extend that selection to multiple consecutive pages?

Comment: It would be interesting we could see at least some pages of your target file, so we could strive for a proper solution

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you try to select the text with your mouse, and by the looks of it, you didn't enable mouse support...

If I'm right, the easy fix is to enable mouse support:

```
:set mouse=a
```

(see `:help mouse`)